# Why doesn't setting icon to null on an AlertDialog subclass hide the icon?

Tags: android, icons, android-alertdialog

I have a subclass of ActivityDialog that is instantiated using Activity.showDialog() and Activity.onCreateDialog().

In my subclasses overridden version of ActivityDialog.onCreate(), I can change the icon by calling setIcon(R.drawable.some_drawable_resource).

However, oddly, I can't make the default  icon not show by calling setIcon(null).  Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: setIcon(int resId)
Set resId to 0 if you don't want an icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is, how do I hide the icon, you can call a different method to do this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setIcon(int)

Call the above method and pass in the int literal 0.  (That is, according to the documentation.  I have not tried this myself.)

As for why setting the icon to null doesn't hide the icon, you will have to ask the developers themselves.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I'd (wrongly) assumed that setIcon() worked the same way for AlertDialog as AlertDialog.Builder where   AlertDialog.Builder.setIcon(null) hides the icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement your own layout for the dialog where you don't specify a icon.